# Is it ok storing the img src in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a rich text component in my form and can add text, images, video etc. Everything gets saved in one field in Cloud Firestore. When I include images with the text, they come up as `src="...."` in between the text which is fine. But what does this mean? Do the images get stored into Cloud Firestore? I know you're not supposed to do that. Is Firebase going to charge me in the future if I have a lot of images/videos etc?

As the images get passed as part of the 'content' field that can include text, you can't separate them and store them in storage. At least I don't think so.

I guess what I'm asking is, is this ok? Am I going to have any issues in the future in terms of how many images the db can handle or being charged for it? I just don't understand where the images are being saved.

[image: Screenshot of a document in Cloud Firestore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your screenshot is a base64 encoded image. So all the data for the image is encoded in the URL itself.

This is not uncommon for smaller images, as it saves the browser from having to make another request to get the image. And as long as your total document size remains under the 1MB limit that Firestore has, it is in itself fine.

If you see this regularly and the images are non-trivial, you might want to see if you can extract the binary data and store it in Cloud Storage. One reason for that is cost control: on Firestore you pay $0.18/GiB, while on Storage that is $0.026/GB (as per the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)).